# Delphi - Converting an array of type to an array of string

Tags: arrays, string, delphi, types

I'm currently programming in Delphi and need to convert the array 'BookArray : array of TBook' to BookArray2 : array of string'.
Is there a function or anyway to convert a type array to a string array?

Thanks, George.

Comment: We don't know what a `TBook` is, so we cannot answer. Also, you must define what this 'conversion' actually should do. (Finally, I have no idea what a 'type array' is...)

Comment: yes, please provide declaration of your custom TBook type.

Answer (score 3):

You need a function that converts your type to a string. Let us suppose that it exists like this:

```
function BookToString(const Book: TBook): string;
```

Then you apply the function to each element of your array:

```
function BookArrayToString(const Books: array of TBook): TArray<string>;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Books));
  for i := 0 to high(Books) do
    Result[i] := BookToString(Books[i]);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard function to do that. You would need to go over your tbook array and step by step and convert what's in there to a string and put that in the stringarray.

```
SetLength(BookArray2, length(BookArray))
for i := 0 to High(BookArray) do begin
  BookArray2[i] := BookArray[i].Author + ' ' + BookArray[i].Title + ' ' + IntToStr(BookArray[i].Edition);
end;
```

Comment: Hmm. `SetLength` should be outside the loop.

Comment: @Pieter - "There is no standard function" but there is! For classes it is .ToString method: `BookArray2[i] := BookArray[i].ToString();` http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.TObject.ToString and for recotds it is Operator Implisit: `BookArray2[i] := BookArray[i];` http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi) // the imlementation should be proided by the topicstarter, but at lease the prefered name/method fo conversion was set

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why should setlength be used outside the loop?

Comment: Because you know before the loop begins the final size of the array. And so you can allocate once. And so avoid expensive calls to heap allocation and avoid fragmenting address space.

Comment: Also pred(Length(...)) should be high(...)